# How should I use identifierForVendor during development?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

Apple recommends using [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.  The value of this changes every time one runs their application within the iOS simulator.

Initial functionality in my application requires that I recognize the device as a form of light authentication.  This makes development tedious, and ideally I could persist a unique value across debug / run sessions.  Are there any recommendations for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's pretty [clearly documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) that this value will change when building and running in the simulator. On a real device, it will only change when the user deletes all of your apps from their device and reinstalls the app.

If you want the simulator app to use a consistent identifier during development you could define that UUID and use it for simulator builds only:

```
NSUUID *devId;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
devId = [NSUUID initWithUUIDString:@"SOME-STATIC-UUID-STRING"];
#else
devId = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
#endif
```

Note that you need to replace SOME-STATIC-UUID-STRING with a real UUID string.

Comment: Hi Ryan.  Yes I understand that this is unique to the simulator. I'm asking how others have worked around it during development.

Comment: Usually I have built apps so that they don't depend on that property for anything critical (usually just a caching of a login token by device). If you absolutely need it, generate a UUID once and use that in a bit of conditional compilation (updating my answer to show you what this would look like) for the simulator builds.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the update.  I had implemented something similar, and I'll update the question to reflect, because it isn't effective in a team environment.  Perhaps my approach is wrong, or this will just be like testing notifications, which isn't possible in the simulator.

Comment: By the way, your target check is cleaner than my string check obviously, so thanks.

Comment: If you're depending on the identifierForVendor for something that critical that you really need it to be different for every developer, you may have a bad time of it when the app is in production. Simply reinstalling the app or restoring from a backup will reset that identifier.

Comment: I'm starting to see identifierForVendor reset randomly on my Enterprise Distribution apps now, even without deletion of the app or restore.  I'm moving toward a Keychain key approach now.

Comment: Yep, Bek - I have never had a consistent identifierForVendor for my enterprise apps.  Each app gets its own identifierForVendor.  I have submitted a bug report to Apple (like 6 months ago) and haven't heard anything back.  Can you share your keychain approach?  I was leaning toward using NSUUID and storing it.

Comment: The link OP added mentioned nothing about `id`

Answer (score 0):

As of May 8, 2023

**`identifierForVendor`**

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

My guess is that every time we kill simulator and start again, we get a new "phone", so a new device Id.